# Little endian architecture,

Tags: computer-architecture

Address 0000 stores 0xde

0001 stores 0xad

0002 stores 0xbe

0003 stores 0xef

Treat the data stored as 2 16 bit integers, what are the two values stored?

I thought the answer would be 0xadde and 0xefbe but I was wrong. Why?

Comment: CS = Computer Science. Is this "science" in your opinion?

Comment: @gnasher729 This is a perfectly reasonable question about endianness, a basic concept in computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's program it and see what happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  unsigned char mem[4] = { 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef };

  printf("%02hhx %02hhx %02hhx %02hhx\n", mem[0], mem[1], mem[2], mem[3]);
  printf("%04hx %04hx\n", *(unsigned short *)(mem), *(unsigned short *)(mem + 2));
}
```

Here is the output:

```
de ad be ef
adde efbe
```